# Compiling C++ dll Visual Studio linking error with crt library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm having a hard time compiling a C/C++ dll on Visual Studio. It seems to be linked to CRT library.

A simple VS c++ dll project. Just removed recompiled header, and added /NOENTRY. Exporting methods is working, but a simple class (not intended to be exported)  raises a lot of linking error with CRT library:

Test.h:

```
class ITest
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class Test final : public ITest
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    void foo();
};

// extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ITest* __cdecl CreateTest();
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"
Test::Test() {}
Test::~Test() {}
Test::foo() {}
// extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ITest* __cdecl CreateTest() { return new Test; }
```

errors:

```
Test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
msvcrt.lib(delete_scalar.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol free referenced in function "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPEAX@Z)
```

Uncommenting the export raises more msvcrt.lib link errors and changing the runtime library for MDd, MT, MTd changes only the library referenced.

Thanks you for any help :)

Comment: please provide a [mcve], is the error when compiling your dll or when linking to your dll? Are you using external libraries? If so which runtime do those libraries use?

Comment: This actually is the minimal example, the original code is larger but is still related to crt library. I just created a VS dll project with no other libraries or dlls. Only in Project Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library : /MD that references msvcrt.lib. The problem is when I compile the dll

Comment: Can't reproduce, have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Yes, I just figured the problem, (I've edited the point in the question). It's because I had put /NOENTRY but I wonder why it raises those errors as /NOENTRY should be for resource only dll which I belive is the case

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from /NOENTRY option in Project Properties->Linker->Advanced->No Entry Point. Removing it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

`/NOENTRY` is for creating dlls which don't have any code at all and only contiain bitmaps etc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-a-resource-only-dll?view=vs-2017

As the dll (should) have no code visual studio doesn't link in the runtime library either, but as there is code it generates requirements for the runtime library symbols which are unresolved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I interpreted the short description differently as the default dll project has a dllMain I thought it was talking about that